# How can I make Cropper.js work with images from URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, cropperjs

I am trying to get Cropper.js working on a URL images from the web.

https://github.com/fengyuanchen/cropperjs

It is working fine when I upload an image from my device but when it comes to an online picture.. I have tons of errors, including:

> From origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

The cropper doesnt show up on the image and I gave the Cors error.

Here's my code:

```
$(function($) {
  $("#submit").click(function() {
    var selectedFile = $("#imglink").val();
    $("#photo").attr("src", selectedFile);
    var image = document.getElementById("photo");
    console.log(image);
    const cropper = new Cropper(image, {
      aspectRatio: 16 / 9,
      cropBoxResizable: false
    });
    cropper.crop();
    $("#crop-button").on("click", function() {
      cropper.getCroppedCanvas().toBlob(function(blob) {
        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append("croppedImage", blob);
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "img/index.php",
          data: formData,
          processData: false,
          contentType: false,
          success: function(data) {},
          error: function(err) {}
        });
      });
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `toDataURL` function of canvas to convert the image into base64 then load it again into `image.src`.

```
var canvas = cropper.getCroppedCanvas()

//replacing the image url with base64 data
image.src = canvas.toDataURL(); 

canvas.toBlob(function(blob) {
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("croppedImage", blob);
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "img/index.php",
      data: formData,
      processData: false,
      contentType: false,
      success: function(data) {},
      error: function(err) {}
    });
}
```

Hope it will works!

Comment: Thank you for this quick answer. Actually my problem is that when I load my photo form the Url, I have it display but I don't have the cropper coming on. And I have a CORS error at this point.

Comment: Actually I was trying to work from a protected URL.... Could have never worked.... Thanks again for your help

Comment: So, the issue is only with the protected URL? if yes, then can u share that URL here?

Comment: I think.... https://padelmagazine.fr/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/photo-1456983933114-c22026990f4b-3.jpeg    I chose it randomly..

Comment: I'm facing the same. Upload works well but the problem is that when I load the image with JS, it seems that cropper.js is accessing to the image URL again to S3 and it is failing with 403 error

Comment: {... checkCrossOrigin: false,...} use this option parameter when start cropperjs